# How to convert .dat to .csv using python? the data is being expressed in one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

Hi i'm trying to convert .dat file to .csv file.
But I have a problem with it.
I have a file .dat which looks like(column name)

```
region GPS name ID stop1 stop2 stopname1 stopname2 time1 time2 stopgps1 stopgps2
```

it delimiter is a tab.

so I want to convert dat file to csv file.
but the data keeps coming out in one column.

i try to that, using next code

```
import pandas as pd
with open('file.dat', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([l.rstrip() for l in f.read().split()])
```

and

```
with open('file.dat', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLine = line.strip('\t').split()
        newLines.append(newLine)
with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

But all the data is being expressed in one column.
(i want to express 15 column, 80,000 row, but it look 1 column, 1,200,000 row)
I want to convert this into a csv file with the original data structure.
Where is a mistake?

Please help me... It's my first time dealing with data in Python.

Comment: Try reading it as a csv with a `sep` value of `"\t"` : `pd.read_csv("file.dat", sep="\t")`, if that fails try explicitly passing `None` : `pd.read_csv("file.dat", sep=None)`. It might fail, but if it succeeds that's definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using pandas, you can just use `pd.read_csv()` with another delimiter:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.dat", sep="\t")
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

See also the [documentation for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: It's probably worth nothing that those weird `dat` files often tend to have spaces as delimiter, instead of tab, so if `'\t'` fails, try a length of spaces: `'\s{4}'`

Comment: Thank you:) You solved the problem.